# How to solve this equation after using Taylor formula?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I can`t understand this transformation after using Taylor formula:
$$...=x(1+ \frac{1}{3}( \frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{x^2}+ \frac{1}{x^3})+ o(\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{x^2}+ \frac{1}{x^3}) = x + \frac{1}{3}+o(\frac{1}{x}) + o(1)= x +\frac{1}{3}+o(1)$$ 
Can you explain it please?Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We consider $x\rightarrow \infty$. We say that $f(x)=o(g(x))$ if $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists and is equal to $0$.

> Keeping this in mind we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> &\color{blue}{x\left(1+ \frac{1}{3}\left( \frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{x^2}+ \frac{1}{x^3}\right)
> + o\left(\frac{1}{x}+ \frac{1}{x^2}+ \frac{1}{x^3}\right)\right)}\\
> &\qquad=x+\frac{1}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)
> +o\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\tag{1}\\
> &\qquad=x+\frac{1}{3}+o\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\tag{2}\\
> &\qquad=x+\frac{1}{3}+o\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &\qquad\color{blue}{=x+\frac{1}{3}+o(1)}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we multiply with  $x$ and note that $x^ko(x^l)=o(x^{k+l})$.
- In (2) we observe that the terms $\frac{1}{x}$ and $\frac{1}{x^2}$ are swallowed by
  $o\left(1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$.
- In (3) we have $\frac{1}{x^2}=o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ when $x\rightarrow \infty$.
- In (4) we have  $\frac{1}{x}=o\left(1\right)$ when $x\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Thank you!! I understood your explanation.

Comment: @PashaMinigun: You're welcome! Good to see the answer is useful. :-)